# ALSA issues with pyaudio in Kali VM

Tags: python, pyaudio, alsa, python-sockets

I've tried many codes now and many config options but I can't fix this output. This is from the server side, client doesn't output any error. The point is to either send or receive live sound from server/client. The server code I last tried is this:

```
import socket
import pyaudio

# Socket
HOST = IPADDRES
PORT = PORT

# Audio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
CHUNK = 1024 * 4
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

with socket.socket() as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connection from " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))

    data = conn.recv(4096)
    while data != "":
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        stream.write(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

And this is the terminal output:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5690:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5690:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:491:(a52_slave_hw_params_half) Cannot set slave rate 48000
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
Connection from IPADDRESS:PORT
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8568:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

Only ctl+c makes it stop but the underrun part prints endlessly while running. I'm using Kali in a VM, Windows Direct Sound and Audio Intel HD selected in VM config. Kali config also Intel HD, I can reproduce sound from webpages and all, just coding it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install pipewire-pulse
```

and make sure the toggle button in the volume section is enabled, by default it is disabled.

Then restart your machine and you should be good to go.